# Back button redirects

Tags: 2013, redirect

I'm currently implementing SharePoint on a test server.  One of the issues I've run into is that SharePoint appears to redirect you back to the current page when you click the back button in the browser.  I've seen this behavior on other sites and it's always very annoying.  I can almost guarantee that the question of how to address this issue will come up.

I was surprised when I didn't find anything on a google search and so I turn to you.  Is there a way to change SharePoint's redirect behavior or make it respect browser back buttons?